# Trouble Using Vector's addAll( ) function when the Vector is in a containing class

Tags: java, vector, subclass

Using Java 6 SE, I have a class that contains a Vector. There is a class method that simply calls the contained Vector's addAll() method with the same parameters for each. The Vectors can be of either type "Superclass" or type "Subclass" and I want the addAll() methods to support both. This whole setup might look like this:

```
public class VectorAContainer(){
    this.vectorA = new Vector<Superclass>();
}

public void addAll(Vector<Superclass> vector){
    this.vectorA.addAll(vector);
}
```

Then I want to call a line of code like this:

```
VectorAContainer container = new VectorAContainer();
container.addAll(vectorB); //where vectorB is a Vector<Subclass>
```

The problem is, Eclipse gives the following error:

> "The method addAll(Vector<Superclass>) in the type
>   VectorAContainer is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Vector<Subclass>)."

Strangely, I have found that addAll() works if it's NOT inside of a class:

```
//No container with an addAll(), calling directly on vectorA
this.vectorA.addAll(vectorB); //No errors!
```

I don't see a difference between the two above cases. I would like to get the first way to work because I have a much more elaborate class that contains a Vector like the one above. I would greatly appreciate any help you all could provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accept a covariant generic parameter:

```
public void addAll(Collection<? extends Superclass> c)
```

You can see this in the [declaration of `addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

> ```
> boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's because Superclass is a lower bound annotation meaning classes that are Super to Vector. If vectorB is a subclass to Vector then it won't work. AbstractList and AbstractCollection are Super to Vector. I believe you want to use. 
    `public void addAll(Vector<? extends Vector> vector){
         vectorA.addAll(vector);
     }`

**P.S. Vector is an obsolete class. You should use ArrayList if you don't need a thread safe implementation.**

*P.P.S. You don't need to use "this" unless you have two variables with the same name (e.g.

`private Variable variableA;`

`public void example(Variable variableA){`

`this.variableA = variableA;`

`}`

Comment: Vector is obsolete? I see nothing about it in the JavaDoc for Java 6 or 7. So far as I can tell, the only difference is that Vector is thread safe whereas ArrayList is not.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. It hasn't been declared obsolete. I guess it's just been recognized by the community as being less useful than ArrayList because it synchronizes on every operation rather than a whole sequence of operations.